# Simplfy trigonometric functions by only considering integer inputs?

Tags: trigonometry

I have the below function which only takes integer input,

$$ 2 \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  t}{3}\right)+\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{3}\right)-\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  t}{3}\right)+6 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  t}{3}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{3}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  t}{3}\right) $$

The resulting output from $t=0$ to $t=10$ is $\{8, 8, -4, -4, -4, -4, 8, 8, -4, -4, -4\}$, and this pattern repeats indefinitely.

Is there a systematic way of reducing this expression using the fact we only consider integer input?

Comment: You already have. You've defined a function $n \mapsto f(n)$ from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ by saying $f(n)$ is $8$ if $n \equiv 0, 1 \bmod 5$ and $f(n) = -4$ otherwise.

Comment: That's true, but I am really looking for a continuous function which agrees at the integers.

Comment: @User You could resort to some kind of interpolation for such a function.

Comment: If you only care about values at the integers, then all functions *are* continuous, because the integers' natural topology (inherited from the reals) is that of a discrete space. Besides, you already *have* a lovely continuous-on-the-reals expression that gives you the values you want. Since you're hoping for something periodic, a sine-and-cosine expression is just about the nicest thing around.

Comment: Perhaps I am being ungrateful about how nice it is. I guess it is very speculative but I just thought there may be an even simply combination of Sin and Cos, given how simple the time series is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $t$ is an integer,
$$ \sin(\tfrac{4\pi t}{3}) = \sin(2\pi t - \tfrac{2\pi t}{3})
= \sin(2\pi t)\cos(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3}) - \cos(2\pi t)\sin(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3})
= -\sin(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3}) $$
and similarly
$$ \cos(\tfrac{4\pi t}{3}) = \cos(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3}) $$
Thus
\begin{align*}
& 2\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi t}{3})
+ \sqrt3\sin(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3})
- \sqrt3\sin(\tfrac{4\pi t}{3})
+ 6\cos(\tfrac{\pi t}{3})
+ \cos(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3})
+ \cos(\tfrac{4\pi t}{3}) \\
&= 2\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi t}{3}) + 6\cos(\tfrac{\pi t}{3})
+ 2\sqrt3\sin(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3}) + 2\cos(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3}) \\
&= 4\sqrt3 \left(\tfrac12 \sin(\tfrac{\pi t}{3})
  + \tfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos(\tfrac{\pi t}{3})\right)
+ 4 \left(\tfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3})
  + \tfrac12\cos(\tfrac{2\pi t}{3}) \right) \\
&= 4\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}) + 4 \cos(\tfrac{\pi (2t-1)}{3}) \\
&= 4\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}) - 4 \cos(\tfrac{\pi (2t-1)}{3}+\pi) \\
&= 4\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}) - 4 \cos(\tfrac{2\pi (t+1)}{3}) \\
&= 4\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}) - 4 \cos\big(\pi(t+1)-\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}\big)\\
&= 4\sqrt3 \sin(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}) - (-1)^{t+1} 4 \cos(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3})\\
&= 8\left(\tfrac{\sqrt3}{2} \sin(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3}) + (-1)^t\tfrac12\cos(\tfrac{\pi (t+1)}{3})\right)\\
&= 8\sin(\tfrac\pi6(2t+2+(-1)^t))
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}\sin\left(\frac{4\pi t}{3}\right) &= \sin\left(\frac{6\pi t}{3} - \frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)\\
&= \sin\left(2\pi t - \frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)\\
&= - \sin \left(\frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)\end{align}$$

For the cosine part,

$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac{4\pi t}{3}\right) &= \cos\left(\frac{6\pi t}{3} - \frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)\\
&= \cos\left(2\pi t - \frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)\\
&= \cos \left(\frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)\end{align}$$

If we apply these two identitiesto the given expression, then we have

$$ 2 \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  t}{3}\right)+2\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{3}\right)+6 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  t}{3}\right)+2\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{3}\right)\\ $$

With the so-called '[R-Formulae](http://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php)', this becomes

$$\sqrt{48}\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{3} + \arctan{\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}}\right) + \sqrt{16}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{3} + \arctan{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)\\
= {4\sqrt{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{3} + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) + 4\sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$
$$= {4\sqrt{3}\sin\left(\frac{(t + 1)\pi t}{3}\right) + 4\sin\left(\frac{(4t + 1)\pi t}{6}\right)}$$

... and this is as far as I got.

I am unsure what you mean by "systematic". If you are referring to a general approach of summing up $\sin$'s and $\cos$'s that does not depend on one's observation skills, then perhaps you can make use of complex numbers.

Sum up the sines by summing up their corresponding complex numbers and taking the imaginary part of the result, and then do the same for the cosines, this time taking the real part of the result.